# Divisibility problem.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, divisibility

In line written squares of natural numbers from 1 to 2012. How many of these numbers have a remainder when divided by 17, which is divisible by 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  make a list of the squares of the numbers $0$ through $16$ and compute the remainder on dividing by $17$.  See how many and which ones they are.  There are $\lfloor \frac {2102}{17} \rfloor=118$ complete cycles and a bit.

Comment: I can't create rule to explain this. I have found two squares, which remainder on dividing by 17 is divisible by 3. It's 10 and 14, but i do not understand the next step.

Comment: @DanSh:  There are two others.

Comment: @DanSh:  The idea is that if $m^2$ has a remainder divisible by $3$ when divided by $17,$ so will $(m+17k)^2=m^2+34mk+289k^2$ because the last two terms are divisible by $17$

Comment: Still do not understand. what can i get from $(m+17k)^{2} = m^{2} + 34mk + 289k^{2}$? the last two terms are divisible, this is okey, but it is my start conditions, that $m^{2}$ must be divided by 17.

Comment: @DanSh:  It means that the cycle will repeat every $17$.  Just as $10^2 \equiv 15 \pmod {17}$, so are $(10+17)^2, (10+2\cdot 17)^2, \ldots$